# Get source code of a JavaScript class constructor

Tags: javascript, reflection, metaprogramming

I need to create a method `GetCode` returning a string with the source code of a constructor function for any class. For instance,

```
let code = GetCode (class CX {
  constructor () {
    this.x = 1
    this.y = 1
    this.fx ()
    this.fy ()
  }
  fx () {}
  fy () {}
})
```

should return some similar than this in the `code` variable:

```
`
  this.x = 1
  this.y = 1
  this.fx ()
  this.fy ()
`
```

For regular methods such as `fx` or `fy` a simple `.toString` invocation is enough. But when that is done on the constructor function, the returned string is the whole text of the class and not the inner source code of the function. I have tried to parse the string returned by `CX.toString ()` to fetch exactly the fragment of text I need using tools such as `JSCodeShift` but the fingerprint is too heavy (5Mb).

I wonder if would be possible to devise a hack to get the string with the source code I need.

Other Example:

```
let code = GetCode (class CX {
  constructor ({ min, max }) {
    if (min < max) {
      for (let x = min; x < max; x++) {
        console.log (x)
      }
    } 
    this.min = min
    this.max = max
  }
  fmin () { return this.min }
  fmax () { return this.min }
})
```

Comment: If you transpile it to ES5, it adds the methods to the `prototype` and the code inside the `constructor` is added to the constructor function. [Babel link](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcQKZQMJwCaoBTBgCUiA3gFACQECAznADaoB0DcA5gWM1HAMpQATjDCciRcgF9y5NJhz4IDAIa1aiDAA0y5RIhphaQkNDiDEeEhUpQAFjFrMAHogC8iAIxU7D5gE83T297R2AAy11EaT1gF0syaUkiIA&debug=false&evaluate=false&sourceType=script&presets=env%2Ces2015-loose&targets=&version=7.12.10) (With *ES2015-loose* preset. ES2015 preset adds additional checks)

Comment: (This will also transpile `super()`, `let` and other ES2015+ syntax inside the constructor. So, not a foolproof hack)

Answer (score 1):

So, I got the solution. Follow following steps -

1. Get the Class and convert it to string using `toString()`.
2. Get the `constructor` part of the resulting string using regexp.
3. Break the substring into array. Perform `pop()` and `shift()` to remove unnecessary part of array.
4. Finally, join the array as a string.

The below snippet explains it all -

```js
console.log(getCode(class CX {
  constructor () {
    this.x = 1;
    this.y = 1;
    this.fx ();
    this.fy ();
  }
  fx () {}
  fy () {}
}));

console.log(getCode(class CX {
  constructor ({ min, max }) {
    if (min < max) {
      for (let x = min; x < max; x++) {
        console.log (x)
      }
    } 
    this.min = min
    this.max = max
  }
  fmin () { return this.min }
  fmax () { return this.min }
}));

function getCode(inputClass){
  let regx = /constructor[\s\S]+?(?=}\n[A-Za-z\s\*]*\(\)[\s]*{)/g;
  let code = inputClass.toString();
  let arr = code.match(regx)[0].split("\n");
  arr.pop();
  arr.shift();
  return arr.join("\n");
}
```

Comment: Wow!! incredible simple & elegant with RegExps. Your solution already fit my cases. But for the shake of generality, ¿hoy do you extend your code to consider restructuring on constructor parameters? Something like `constructor ({ name, age }) { ...`

Comment: @JavierVélez I have edited the snippet for this case also. In the regex, check that the closing bracket (`}`) is immediately followed by a new line character. Check my answer for details. I have also included an example of this type.

Comment: Amazing! but I'm not sure if RegExps are so powerful. When { & } are added in the constructor it seems the function does not work properly. Please take a glance at the new example added at the end of the question

Comment: They are powerful indeed! Check my updated snippet. I have inserted you example in the snippet.

Comment: This will fail if a developer comments out the constructor, and then adds a non commented constructor before it.  It will also fail if a class has a property assigned a string containing code that looks like a constructor.